# Is there a canary property to check in nginx-ingress snippet

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, canary-deployment

I have these two ingresses for a blue (production) and green (canary) deployment and I want in my nginx snippet to set certain stuff based on whether the request is served from production service or from  canary. What should be the `if` statement in the snippet?

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: blue-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if (canary) { <--- WHAT CAN I CHECK HERE?
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }
spec:
  ...
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: green-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-cookie: "green"
spec:
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific *canary property* you can check against.
You could, however, look for specific *cookie*, that your canary service could provide

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "id=([^;]+)(?:;|$)") {
    ...
}
```

Note that, while nginx does have [`if` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if), there is no `else`. *The equivalent for else would be all that isn't modified with an `if`*.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I don't have a cookie to test in the statement, I mean I can set a cookie in blue-ingress but not in green-ingress because it's a canary one that does not support nginx snippet

Comment: I believe there is no other possible solution.

Comment: @p10l: Your answer with regards to the else equivalent for else did help me solve my issue.

Comment: would be nice if you share the final configuration, if you dont mind.

Comment: Normally canary deployment is done with annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight.
     
But if you need to customize response headers depending on the ingress really used, you won't be able to do it because this annotation can not be mixed with for example nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet annotation. 

By the way few weeks ago I tried to ask nearly the same question and my question was refused because this subject is not related to dev. I feel very bad for the way this website is managed.